# How to compare dictionary to the list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries and a dictionary. I need to compare each of the dictionaries in the list to the separate dictionary and print out the specific key if matched.

For example:

```
# The list of dictionaries is created out of csv file
list_of_dicts = {
    OrderedDict([('name', 'Alice'), ('A', '2'), ('G', '8'), ('C', '3')])
    OrderedDict([('name', 'Bob'), ('A', '4'), ('G', '1'), ('C', '5')])
    OrderedDict([('name', 'Charlie'), ('A', '3'), ('G', '2'), ('C', '5')])
}

sep_dict = {'name': 0, 'A': 4, 'G': 1, 'C': 5}

for i in list_of_dicts:
    if i == sep_dict:
        sep_dict['name'] = i['name']
```

After comparing I want to update sep_dict 'name' key according to the list_of_dicts. I know there are similar questions on the internet, but I'm still new to programming to python and cannot figure out how to implement them. I've tried simple for loop and if statement but they do not work. I've also tried to transfer dictionaries to set, but cannot understand the logic behind it.

Comment: 1) list_of_dicts seems invalid, did you mean this ``[OrderedDict()...]`` 2) What is the expected output ?

Comment: Yes, it's incorrect. I've copied it from terminal windows, its already an output.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to solve, this sounds like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: Mark, thank you for your reply. I have described everything that I need to achieve. I need to find if dictionary_1 can be found in list of dictionaries (list: dictionary_1; dictionary_2; dictionary_3 and etc). If it is found then I need to print out the specific key to the terminal. I do not know how to find match of dictionary_1 in list of dictionaries.

Comment: From your code snippet.

1. Your "list_of_dicts" is not a list, it's a dictionary.
2. While comparing "sep_dict" with each of the dictionaries in the "list_of_dicts", note that your value types are different, which are sensitive in python.
3. When two dictionaries are same, what's the point of "sep_dict['name'] = i['name']"? They are already equivalent if the pre-condition i.e. "i ==  sep_dict" evaluates to true.

Comment: The thing is that the sep_dict is made from a text file. That's why I need to compare them. Simple, '==' won't work... What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
# list of dictionaries
list_of_dicts = [
    {"name": "john", "age": 30, "colour": "red"},
    {"day": 1, "month": 7, "year": 2010},
    {"item": "apple", "cost": 55, "name": "pink lady"},
]

sep_dict = {'name': 0, 'A': 4, 'G': 1, 'C': 5}

for dictionary in list_of_dicts:
    for key in dictionary:
        if key in sep_dict:
            print(key)
            # update sep_dict however you like, although note that
            # there may be multiple dictionaries with the same key
            # in list_of_dicts
            sep_dict[key] = dictionary[key]
```

This is something similar to what you were trying to do, just comparing the keys in `sep_dict` and each dictionary in `list_of_dicts`.

---

You can iterate through key-value pairs:

```py
for dictionary in list_of_dicts:
    for key,value in dictionary.items():
        if key in sep_dict:
            print(key, ":", value)
```

---

Alternatively you might consider using list comprehensions to get a list of all key-value pairs that share a key with `sep_dict`, and then do whatever you want with it. This is essentially identical to the previous code block, but is more concise.

```py
common = [(k,d[k]) for d in list_of_dicts for k in sep_dict if k in d]
#> [('name', 'john'), ('name', 'pink lady')]
for k,v in common:
    print(k, ":", v)
#> name : john
#> name : pink lady
```